# Post upgrade WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 to 4.0.0 getting error while testing APIs

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

We are getting error response *"The requested resource is not available."* for all the APIs, Post upgrade from WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 to 4.0.0. Kindly suggest to resolve this issue.

During the upgradation process we did not get any error on wso2carbon.log file.

Comment: Can you make sure all the artifacts are deployed correctly on the migrated APIM 4 pack without any errors? Are there are any error logs while starting up the updated pack?

Comment: We are not getting any error while starting up the APIM 4 service. We are getting the error while hitting the API resource. i.e PizzaShack API

Comment: Unlike 3.2.0, there's an extra step before publishing the API. Can you redeploy the API and see whether you can invoke it?

Comment: We have redeploy the API and tried, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Hi All, Kindly help on this issue.